# Calculations for grid based games

Tags: game-theory

For a grid game to match items in chains of 3 or more, how can a difficulty be calculated?

I have a number of moves, and a grid with a cell count and an element type count n, e.g. 6 different elements/types. Matching elements gives 20 score per element in a chain, e.g. 60 for a 3 element chain. If additional matches occur during the same move a multiplier is applied so e.g. the second 3 element chain will give 120 points.

I would like to be able to use a formula with the variables and then apply a difficulty variable to the outcome, so e.g. there could be a minimum score, and then 3 other levels or rankings for the score they got.

How can this be calculated with the given variables and an additional difficulty variable?

The game is a one player game, which fills a grid with elements/objects. The player then gets a number of moves. When they match a sequence in the grid, new items are dropped in to replace them, which could trigger new matches.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what a "grid game to match items in chains" is. Is this a one player game? Two player? Do you place the items wherever you want? What are the "items"?

Comment: @JackM - I updated my question

Comment: What is a "move"? Does the grid start empty and you place objects to create matches..? Or does it start filled and you swap pieces? Is it partially filled and you move the pieces around...? Where do the new items appear when the old ones vanish?

Comment: It starts filled and you swap pieces. So initially it is filled and has possible matches, if after the user matches items and there are no moves, it reorders the grid to a new set with possible matches. items falls downwards to fill gaps, starting with the lowest items first. E.g. if a row at the bottom is matched, then the rows above fall, filling the place of each row and then the empty top row is filled with new items.

Comment: Okay, I see now. So what is it exactly that you want? You want a way of assigning a "difficulty score" to any given initial state of the board? Or a way of fixing a reasonable "target score" for a given board?

Comment: Yes exactly, a way of defining a target score and additional score targets for e.g 2 or 3 levels of skills

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very mathematical answer, but I don't think there is a good mathematical approach. I would simply create a program to play completely randomly. Have it play maybe ten thousand games and look at the statistics on what kinds of scores it gets. Base your target scores on percentiles: On easy mode, you simply have to get a better score than in 70% of those random games, on normal mode better than 90%, and on hard mode better than 99%. You will have to adjust those numbers by actually testing your game out with real human players to find out if they're too high or too low.

Comment: yeah, that is an approach. I just wondered if there is some formula for existing technique.